# Bitmap resizing in Android with bicubic interpolation

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have a big resolution bitmap, and I'd like to make a thumbnail out of it (of course, it is a dynamic case, I don't have the files in advance, but just to simplify).

However, whatever I do, the bitmap always gets 'nearest neighbour' interpolated image.
I tried setting inDither flag, inPreferQualityOverSpeed, inPrefering RGB_8888 bitmap format, and God only knows what not.

Whatever I try, the image is still pixelated.
Trying to downsample it with GIMP echoed beautiful results, so the image is not faulty.

Any idea of a library or an SDK method somewhere that does downscaling with some smarter interpolation, and not nearest neighbour?